# Blank space in xml after and before textview

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]
I'm trying to remove the blank spaces that it creates automatically before and after the textview. How is it possible?

```
       <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ripetisfondo"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:shadowColor="#000000"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:text="@string/titolo1"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </TableRow>
```

That screenshot is taken from Eclipse. When I run the app, half toggle button disappears.

Comment: What would be your desired behavior? The TextView is centered correctly inside the available space.

Comment: That screenshot is taken from Eclipse. When I run the app, half toggle button disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your textview like so:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

This will make the textview expand to fill the available space **AFTER** everything else is laid out on the screen.  Which should let the toggle take the space it needs.

**EDIT**

You may need to wrap that in a LinearLayout to make it work  like I suggested.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

remove `android:layout_gravity="center"` .That why it is centered.

Comment: I want to center it. But before the toggle button ther's a lot of blank space.

Answer (score 0):

You have your XML TextView gravity set to center which is why it is in the center. Set it to what you want or remove it.

Comment: I want to center it. But before the toggle button ther's a lot of blank space.